# Positioning one button and one div using CSS

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a button and a div(which includes a google map). Using their ids in CSS I write `position:relative;` for the div and `position:absolute;` for the button and in HTML i call first the map and then the button. In this case button stays behind the map so I can't see it. On the other hand I tried to use `position:relative;` for the button and `position:absolute;` for the div and I call the button and the div with the same order. In this case I can see the button but not the div. Here is some code:

**HTML**

```
<body onload="initialize()" onunload="GUnload()">
<div id="map"></div>
<button id="button_map_1" onclick="send_data();">Store</button>
```

**CSS**

```
#button_map_1
{
    height:auto;
    width:auto;

    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;

    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;

    background-color:blue;

    font-family: Arial;
    font-size:15px;
    color:white;

    border:0px;
    border-radius: 25px 25px 25px 5px;

    position: relative;
}

#map
{
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you should also give value of `top`,`left`,`right`,`bottom` to get that `#map` as where you want

Comment: did you mess around with `z-index`?

Comment: No i haven't messed around with z-index. Should I?

Comment: Any fiddle of the code?

Comment: @SoorajChandran What do you mean fiddle?

Comment: you can use jsfiddle.net to make a working sample of the code. Or please post your javascript too , so that i can make a fiddle.

Comment: Well, i used top, bottom, left , right, I messed around with z-index and it worked. I had to delete cache first. That's why it did't change the first time. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to position these elements, the way you want to. For example, if you want them side by side, you could alter the map to be smaller then the parent, so the button can stay on the right. Both elements should float left (or right). Here is how:

```
 #button_map_1
    {
        height:auto;
        width:auto;

        padding-top:10px;
        padding-bottom:10px;

        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;

        background-color:blue;

        font-family: Arial;
        font-size:15px;
        color:white;

        border:0px;
        border-radius: 25px 25px 25px 5px;

        position: relative;
        float:left;
    }

    #map
    {
        height: 100%;
        width: 90%;
        position: relative;
        float:left;
    }
```

And of course, you could put them one on top of the other:

```
#button_map_1
        {
            height:auto;
            width:auto;

            padding-top:10px;
            padding-bottom:10px;

            padding-left: 20px;
            padding-right: 20px;

            background-color:blue;

            font-family: Arial;
            font-size:15px;
            color:white;

            border:0px;
            border-radius: 25px 25px 25px 5px;

            position: absolute;
            left:10px;
            top: 10px;
            z-index:10;//or more if that's the case
        }

        #map
        {
            height: 100%;
            position: relative;
            float:left;
        }
```